# Saving shapefile layer as KML with datasourceOptions using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, export, kml

I'm trying to export a shapefile layer to KML format in QGIS , trough Python coding.

The code is:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(inputlayer, outputlayer, "utf-8", coord_system, "KML")
```

But I have to add `dataSourceOption` in the line, because I have to specify a `"nameField"`.

How I can add `dataSourceOption` in the `writeAsVectorFormat` method?
I have see that `dataSourceOption` accept a `QStringList()` but I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datasourceOptions are passed as a list of OGR creation options for the format.

There are 2 ways: `writeAsVectorFormatV2()` and `writeAsVectorFormat()`.

The first one is more neat in my opinion:

```
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "KML"
options.fileEncoding = 'utf-8'
options.datasourceOptions = ["NameField=ulica"]

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer=inputLayer, fileName=fileName, transformContext=QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options=options)
```

Second option:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer=inputLayer,
                                            fileName=fileName,
                                            fileEncoding='utf-8',
                                            destCRS=crs,
                                            driverName="KML",
                                            datasourceOptions=["NameField=ulica"]
                                            )
```

PS. How I found the answer to your question:

[Here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html?highlight=qgsvectorfilewriter#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat) is the documentation of `QgsVectorFileWriter`. The `datasourceOptions` parameter is described as a list of OGR data source creation options.

[Here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/kml.html#creation-options) I looked up KML format Creation options in the GDAL/OGR documentation. Every format has its own specific creation options. If you need to specify any other options you just pass them in the list just as you would pass them if you used OGR/GDAL in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the name of one of the field of shapefile to "NAME" that is the default field take by the writer of the  `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat`.

Comment: Please approve my answer :). I spent some time looking for this and it is the correct approach to your problem